# Formatting a date in ISO 8601 to minute resolution

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to format a date\time value into ISO 8601 but only down to minute resolution.

So in the format of:

2007-03-01T13:00Z

The native toISOString method on Date returns with seconds and fractionals:

2015-09-30T09:50:03.014Z

How can I knock off them parts to get my desired format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a function for this, but below will do what you want using a regex:

```js
console.log(new Date().toISOString().replace(/:\d+.\d+(\w)$/,'$1'))
```

```js
Date.prototype.toISOStringMinute = function() {
  return this.toISOString().replace(/:\d+.\d+(\w)$/,'$1');
}

console.log(new Date().toISOStringMinute())
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for that, wonder why there is no option to specify a format when formatting to ISO8601?